# Gulp. Вопрос по файловой структуре

Tags: gulp

У меня есть папки "app" и "dist". Написано два отдельных таска: первый мониторит файлы в папке "app", а второй выгружает проект в продакшн (папка "dist"). Всё ОК, но есть одна проблема.

В какой-то момент я захотел реализовать подключение на страницы хедера и футера из отдельных файлов. Для этого обычно используется плагин "gulp-rigger", но во всех примерах его использования берётся файл HTML, обрабатывается и закидывается в "dist". И "dist" же и мониторится. Но у меня-то не так.

Как мне реализовать шаблонизацию, чтобы файлы корректно работали в папке "app"?